# How to number rows belonging to the same column value in Tableau

Tags: indexing, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and I'm stuck.
I've something like this.

**Ticket     Theme     Time**
AB          Red        23.6
AB          Red        12.9
AC          Red        15.0
AD          Yellow    12.1
AD          Yellow    23.1
AD          Yellow    11.0

What i want is, I want to add a number column (named index) such that the first row of ticket AB has a column (index) value 0, second row will have a value 1 and so on.

**Ticket     Index      Theme      Time**
AB        ***0***             Red        23.6
AB         ***1***             Red        12.9
AC         ***0***             Red        15.0
AD         ***0***             Yellow    12.1
AD         ***1***             Yellow    23.1
AD         ***2***             Yellow    11.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you define the ordering? Row order in a relational table is undefined in general. Can you explain why you need the index field? Tableau is most efficient when it can use aggregate (group by) queries. When you need to number rows like this, it may be a sign that you won’t be using aggregate queries. Tableau can still work, just its better to use aggregation when you can

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options. All table calculations so get familiar with those.

There's the INDEX() function, but as you want your count to start at 0 and the index starts at 1 then simply -1:

```
INDEX()-1
```

Alternatively there's the FIRST() function. This starts at 0 but counts in -ve numbers so also requires a tweak:

```
FIRST()*-1
```

You could also look at running_sum and running_count. Either way you will need to edit the table calculation to restart every [Ticket]

[image]

Comment: Andy is correct that table calcs in Tableau allow you to use write calculations that take the order of data rows into account. They also operate on the client side upon aggregate data that has been fetched from the data source (which has performance implications for large data sets), and require you to carefully specify the partitioning and addressing for your calculation which can be a bit tricky. Table calcs are a very useful tool, but not always the right the tool for a specific job. So first make sure you can't solve your problem with aggregate or LOD calcs - especially for big data.

Comment: If using a large data set also be careful with the performance of any LOD calcs - especially FIXED, which can cause a big performance hit. As with so many things in Tableau, the right approach depends on the specifics of the problem. There are usually multiple ways to skin the Tableau cat...